# "<select>" remove/change the blue "v" icon next to option?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to remove the blue "v" icon on a  html thing?

Or how can I make it disappear? Or can I change it?

If I want to remove it what are my options?

Comment: That's not a v... that's a checkmark.

Comment: lol '"v" icon on a html thing?' thanks that made me laugh

Comment: Ok i'll give up on that, is it possible to have images in a <option> (For a <select>)?

Comment: I think it must be another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<select>` is not styled by CSS, it's styled by the operating system. You can make it look the way you want by using an CSS+HTML+JavaScript replacement, but that requires a plug-in or a bit of code.

Comment: Ah ha, so not possible to remove icon for my website viewers?

Comment: No, it is not. Not only that but the appearance is different on Mac, Win XP, Win 7 etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) to replace your `<select>` elements with themable JavaScript-based equivalents. Uniform is nice because it degrades gracefully to your original `<select>` box in the absence of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I use this jQuery/CSS plugin to style select boxes: http://www.adamcoulombe.info/lab/jquery/select-box/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have a  be styled exactly as you want is to not use ...

Google 'custom select box' and you'll find a bunch of alternatives (some of the mentioned by others here)

Answer (score 1):

Like pointed by @Diodeus, it's impossible to change `<select>` appearance using CSS.

But you always can hope in jQuery. I suggest you to try the [selectBox](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/selectBox/), a jQuery plugin with does auto select replacement. Very easy and very powerfull.