# html - <select> custom style

Tags: html, css, select, webview, styles

i'm trying to customize the whole style of the  component, and hide the selector image. All graphics style such border, shadows are setted in the previous table. Now i want to remove all style from the selection menu such as the horrible icon to select an item [image]

My original code in jsf:

```
<h:panelGrid class="dropDown">
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selected}"
  id="list" class="test" style="border-style:none; height:31px;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.list}" var="item"
    itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.code}" />
    <f:ajax execute="@this" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
```

This is my style for class .test

```
.test{
    background-color: white;
    clear: both;
    color: black !important;
    font-family: Helvetica !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-style: none;
}
```

My page rendered in html:

```
<select id="list" name="item" class="test" size="1" style="border-style:none; height:31px;"onchange="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'disableBox()','mojarra.ab(this,event,\'valueChange\',\'@this\')')"> 

    <option value="1">al</option>
    ...
    <option value="22">re</option>
</select>
```

But when i open the webpage from a webview (Android) I still see the icon [image]. 
Is it impossible to remove if I'm on a simple Webview? Or what element should I use to remove it? Or, it's another component I could use?

My idea is to hide the icon and allow a user to click on the single line, then the `Android original component` drop down list is opened.

I know that it's styled by the operating system.. any suggestion?

I think it's not usefull.. but I created a simple jsfiddle page where I can test css style modifications.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMy7j/)

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2008/08/styling-options-in-hselectonemenu.html

Comment: yes, I saw it, but i wonder if ther's an easy way to customize the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard JSF html renderkit will render an `h:selectOne` as a simple html select tag with you `f:selectItems`  becoming the child option tags.

```
<select>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

so your question is really is there a way to remove the icon from an html select tag. It really has nothing to do with JSF.

Once you've figured out how to write the html and cssto get the effect you want, you can then write a custom renderer  to reproduce that html.

Comment: hi, i edited my answer, providing more infos and the rendered webpage.  I think it's related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5903975/2015318 . Any suggestion?

Comment: thank you @Steve Atkinson, now I understood lots of things about rendering, html and jsf. I found a solution and shared with all.

Answer (score 1):

Found a working solution with custom css:

Since the component jsf is rendered as , we include all elements inside a , or in this case inside a

```
<h:panelGrid class="parent dropDown">
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selected}"
    id="list" class="test" style="border-style:none; height:31px;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.list}" var="item"
    itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.code}" />
     <f:ajax execute="@this" />
   </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
```

adding the class parent to the panelGrid and defining:

```
  .parent{
        width:98%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .parent select{
        width:100%;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        border: none;
        background: none;    
    }
```

Our jsf component is rendered without the arrow and other components, like borders and shadows.

Answer (score 0):

custom style select  using only html and css not any js/javascript

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/suyogN/39tx46L3/`
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.